# Trying to run vue project but Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel' I installed the dependency npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-env

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at idToPlugin (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:145:14)
  at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:184:20
  at Array.map ()
  at Service.resolvePlugins (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:170:10)
  at new Service (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:32:25)
  at Object. (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js:15:17) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js',
  'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js'
  ]
  }

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having this problem because you did not install `@vue/cli` globally.

Simply run `npm install -g @vue/cli`, should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
npm i @vue/cli-plugin-babel
```